# PHP Login System Doesnt Always Work First Time - No Error Message, Loops Back To Login Page

Tags: php, mysql

The problem I am facing is that when I attempt to login to my PHP website, the login form often does not take the user to the members page after login.
Login does not work first time.
Then, after using the same login credentials again, it works. It does not always happen. Sometimes it works first time no problems, other times, you have to login a second time for it to work.

```
<?php
session_start();
require "connection.php";
include "navigation.php";
if(isset($_SESSION['origURL'])){
    $url = $_SESSION['origURL'];
}
$max_time = (time() - 60*60);
$client = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$check = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM login_attempts WHERE ip_address = '$client' AND time >='$max_time'");
$checkrow = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
$tries = mysqli_num_rows($check);
if($tries == 3){
    header("Location: robot.php");
    exit;
}
if ( isset($_COOKIE['userid']) && (isset($_COOKIE['username']) && ($_COOKIE['userid'] !== ""))){
    header("Location: member.php");
    exit;
}
$error = false;
if(isset($_GET['activated'])){
    $error_msg = "<div style='border: 2px solid green;margin-bottom:5px; padding:7px;'>Token authenticated successfully - your account is now activated.</div>";
}
if(isset($_GET['updated'])){
    $error_msg = "<div style='border: 2px solid orange;margin-bottom:5px; padding:7px;'>Your details have been updated. Please login again for these changes to take effect.</div>";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $var_password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $var_password = strip_tags($var_password);
    $var_password = htmlspecialchars($var_password);
    $var_username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $var_username = strip_tags($var_username);
    $var_username = htmlspecialchars($var_username);
    if (empty($var_username)){
        $error = true;
        $error = 1;
    }else{
        if (empty($var_password)){
            $error = true;
            $error = 1;
        }
    }
    if (!$error){
        $var_password = hash('sha256', $var_password);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT username, password, userid, acc_active FROM users WHERE username = '$var_username'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        $userid = $row['userid'];
        $stat = $row['acc_active'];
        if ($count == 1 && $row['username']==$var_username && $row['password']==$var_password) {
            if($stat == "active" || $stat == "inactive"){
                $_COOKIE['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_COOKIE['userid'] = $row['userid'];
                $userid = $_COOKIE['userid'];
                setcookie("username", $var_username,  time()+30*24*60*60);
                setcookie("userid", $userid,  time()+30*24*60*60);
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM login_attempts WHERE ip_address=?");
                $stmt->bind_param("s",$client);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
                if(isset($url)){
                    header("Location: $url");
                }else{
                    header("Location: member.php");
                }
            }else{
                if($stat == "disabled"){
                    $error_msg = "<div style='border: 2px solid red;margin-bottom:5px; padding:7px;'>Account does not exist, or it is banned/disabled.</div>";
                }
                if($stat == "notverified"){
                    $error_msg = "<div style='border: 2px solid red;margin-bottom:5px; padding:7px;'>Account is inactive. Please check your inbox / spam for activation token.</div>";
                }
            }
        } else {
            $error = 1;
        }
    }else{
        $error = 1;
    }
    if($error == 1){
        $when = time();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login_attempts(ip_address, username, time) VALUES(?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $client, $var_username, $when);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $tries = $tries + 1;
        $error_msg = "<div style='border: 2px solid orange;margin-bottom:5px; padding:7px;'>".$tries. " of 3 login attempts used.</div>";
    }

}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-container">
    <h2 class="login-header">Login</h2>
    <?php echo $error_msg; ?>
    <form method="post" action="" style="text-align:center">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username...(case sensitive)" name="username" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." name="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
        <br />
        or...
        <br />
        <a href="/rail/reset-password" class="login-btn-alt">Reset Password</a>
        <br />
        <a href="/rail/register" class="login-btn-alt">Register Here</a>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any clarification as to why the login doesn't always work first time would be great.
Just to confirm, it is not a failed login. A failed login with incorrect credentials would display a message counting up to 3. There is no error message or problems in the inspect console etc or apache2 error log.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the use of `$checkrow`?

Comment: You know that if your password contains spaces at firsts or last characters, `trim($password)` will provide an invalid password? Same for `strip_tags($password)` and `htmlspecialchars($password)`

Comment: You shouldn't store passwords as plain text, you should use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: @Barmar there is a `hash()` call, but you are right about `password_verify()`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` should never be used to sanitize input. It should only be used when displaying user-provided data on web pages, to prevent XSS.

Comment: Code is prone to SQL injection

Comment: When the login doesn't work, what actually happens? Are they redirected to some other page?

Comment: Why do you assign `$error = true;` and then immediately replace it with `$error = 1;`? You should just use `true/false` for boolean values.

Comment: You shouldn't use cookies for successful login, you should use a session variable. The user can easily change cookies and then impersonate a different user.

Comment: They can also bypass the login check entirely by setting the cookies.

Comment: Thanks, ill look at using session instead of cookies